# R dataframe remains empty

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

For a project I need to import a data file (CSV) in gephi to visualize it. Gephi asks for an input with source and target on a 1:1 basis. My CSV file consists over around 1000 rows with an ID in the first column. In the columns therafter there is an x amount of targets, depending on the source. So source and target are on a 1:x basis Thus I tried to use R to translate one of the dataframes in to the other. Making a longer data frame with just two columns and a duplicate in the first ID as the value of the source column withe a new row in the dataframe for each target that is connected to an ID.

My problem at the moment is that the gephilijst dataframe is not filled after running these lines of code. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code? Thank you!

```
netwerk <- read.csv("P:\\Documents\\uni\\dataMiningR.csv", header  = TRUE)  

#create the new data frame
gephilijst <- data.frame()

#declare variables
i <- 1
t <- 2
rowcount <- 1


#for every row in the dataframe
if(i <= nrow(netwerk) ){


   while(is.null(netwerk[i,t]) == FALSE){
       #Give cell Ai the value of the person id
       gephilijst[rowcount, 1 ] <- netwerk[i, 1]

       #Give the cell Bi the value of the next contact
       gephilijst[rowcount, 2 ] <- netwerk[i, t]

       #raise the numbers to check if there will be a new contact
       t <- t + 1 
       rowcount <- rowcount + 1
}

#reset numbers to go to the next line in the original csv
t <- 2
i <- i + 1 
}
```

The input in netwerk looks like 
1   2   3   4   5
2   3   4   5   6

The desired output would be this:
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
2   3
2   4
2   5
2   6

This example is simplified

Comment: Could you provide a sample of netwerk and the corresponding desired output that would be in gephilijst?

Comment: Of course, it's pretty bad in the comments. So I'll edit the question

Comment: I don't understand your example, from what you've said netwerk looks like a vector, or a 1 column data frame, yet you have netwerk[i,t] in your loop. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reproduce your problem with the code down. But I don't find the problem you describe: the object  `gephilijst` contains something.

```
netwerk <- data.frame(ID = c(1:25), source=runif(25,1,100), target=runif(25,1,100) )


#create the new data frame
gephilijst <- data.frame()

#declare variables
i <- 1
t <- 2
rowcount <- 1


#for every row in the dataframe
if(i <= nrow(netwerk) ){


  while(is.null(netwerk[i,t]) == FALSE){
    #Give cell Ai the value of the person id
    gephilijst[rowcount, 1 ] <- netwerk[i, 1]

    #Give the cell Bi the value of the next contact
    gephilijst[rowcount, 2 ] <- netwerk[i, t]

    #raise the numbers to check if there will be a new contact
    t <- t + 1 
    rowcount <- rowcount + 1
  }

  #reset numbers to go to the next line in the original csv
  t <- 2
  i <- i + 1 
}


> gephilijst
  V1       V2
1  1 40.37779
2  1 78.67263
```